# Android Development - App not loading on emulator, and DDMS not displaying anything?

Tags: java, android, emulation, android-virtual-device, ddms

I feel like i've searched google enough to now be in a position to ask this question without being one of those people who everyone hates. So before i state my problem i'd just like to say if an obvious answer IS on google, feel free to ridicule me as much as your hearts desire.

Whenever i run an AVD, it simply does not appear under devices in DDMS, and does not show up as a running Android device (whenever i try to run an Android application on the emulator).

If i try and launch an AVD along with the application from eclipse, it says it launches fine on eclipse's output, however even after an hour the application does not show up on the emulator, and it is not listed under devices in DDMS?

Many people claim that the emulator takes a long time to start up, however i've waited for over an hour with no luck, and my computer has a very decent if not good spec (2.8GHz Quad Core Q9550), with 4Gbs of RAM.

I'm using the latest version of eclipse for java, the Java JDK 64 bit version, and Windows 7 64x.

Thanks for any responses / help, i've tried to include as much detail as possible, and again i apologise if there is an easy fix or if i have missed a crucial installation step.

Comment: Does your stuff run corectly when launched from outside eclipse? I.e. run the 'android' script from the SDK, launch the AVD from there, connect to it from a command prompt with adb logcat etc... ?

Comment: Would you mind posting the specific version of Eclipse and the Android SDK you are running?  I'm seeing something very similar on the Mac, but I'm able to fix the issue by killing the adb process and restarting Eclipse.  I'm on Eclipse 3.6.2 running ADT 10.0.1v201103111512-11084

Comment: Checking now, sorry about the delay.

Comment: Everything runs normally outside of eclipse, when i say normally, i mean no errors etc. However there's still the issue of the emulator not showing up in DDMS and because of this logcat states absolutely nothing?

Comment: I'm running Eclipse 3.6.2 and 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841

Comment: Ryan - you were exactly right, that does seem to fix it and get the emulator connected etc!

Comment: Are you running eclipse in 32bits ? I mean, are you sure you're running eclipse inside the same jre ?

Answer (score 0):

there is a drop down box next to the screen capture icon....click on that and reset adb while the emulator is running...the ddms then loads up....run the emulator again...app works...the problem that im facing is that the app doesnt seem to connect to the internet...my app requires online info...but for any other offline app it runs...just the issue with resetting adb everytime.I started facing this problem after updating java.Cant seem to uninstall java because of the java error 1723...getting rid of this...should solve my problem i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the adb server gets stuck sometimes. The server runs as a separate process, so it will not restart with Eclipse or your emulator.

Try:
adb kill-server

Once your emulator is running, check if it shows up here:
adb devices